# Reading properties file from $TOMCAT_HOME\lib

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat7

We have a tiny Web Application using Tomcat server. All the database details are in a properties file as key value pairs for the `hibernate.cfg.xml` to read.
To make it easily managable for the server team, the properties file needs to go to `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder. The Hibernate config file is in: `APP_HOME\src\main\resources\hibernate.cfg.xml` 

and it can be accessed by the application classes. 
The hibernate config file doesn't seem to read `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib/myapp.properties`.
My prime requirement is that the properties file should reside in $TOMCAT_HOME/lib.
Can anyone please suggest me the right thing to do.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you V33R and Chetan. Both of your comments had given me a direction.
I used the system property

> catalina.home

instead of **catalina.base** which wasn't pointing to the right location I needed.
The below is what I finally did:

```
    private static Properties extractPropertiesFile() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    String propertiesFilePath = System.getProperty("catalina.home") +
            File.separator + "lib"+ File.separator + "myapp.properties";

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath));

    return properties;
}
```

I had to remove the DB properties which were set in the hibernate.cfg.xml file to the below method. I tried loading the extracted properties file, but was not working as expected and hence loaded them into Hibernate.cfg.Configuration instance as below. 
To build Session Factory:

```
 private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {

        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            Properties properties = extractPropertiesFile();

            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").setProperties(properties);

            // The properties below are extracted from $TOMCAT_HOME/lib/myapp.properties
            configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", properties.getProperty("propertyfile.database.driver.classname"));
            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                    configuration.getProperties()). buildServiceRegistry();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Public Method to get SessionFactory

```
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

    if(sessionFactory == null){
        sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

Comment: Cool.. And good thing you posted what you ended up doing to resolve this so that others can benefit from it. catalina.base should be used however, if you are going to run two instances of tomcat, otherwise catalina.home should be fine..

Comment: I am not sure if a file withing $TOMCAT_HOME/lib can be accessed using the property 'catalina.base' since it points to: workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0. I don't see any reference to the lib folder from here.

Comment: Could be the way you've configured the server in Eclipse. For me, both `catalina.base` and `catalina.home` point to the same location, `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0. ` Anyway, since your code is working, yey!

Comment: Interesting..! I haven't really done anything to the tomcat installation other than modifying the default port number through the Eclipse Server console. I have multiple Tomcats configured on the Eclipse though. Have you done anything with your tomcat setup? Do you have multiple tomcats? Interested to know why 'cataline.home' and 'catalina.base' are the same in your case.

Comment: I use MyEclipse(which is very similar to eclipse). Did nothing but add a server like you'd normally do, point it to the location of Apache, and that's it.. I just have on tomcat installed on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get the path of the properties file:

```
String propertyFilePathStr= System.getProperty("catalina.base") +
                  File.separator + "lib"+ File.separator + "myapp.properties";
```

And then configure Hibernate to use this config file by:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration().configure(propertyFilePathStr);
```

However, not that this will work with Tomcat only and needs to be changed if you are using a different server like Glassfish, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For tomcat it Can be done using this:

```
File configDir = new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base"), "conf");
File configFile = new File(configDir, "myconfig.properties");
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(configFile);
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(stream);
```